# Select statement don't get any data in db C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is my select statement in C#, I try to input where condition by parameter. but when I put parameter this code can't found any data in database.

My data in SQL Server:

```
    900000/2019-10-01/2019-10-01/313225100/143/100103/xxx0020190914/900000/12201/-/2500/2019-10-01 01:45:23.250
    900000/2019-10-01/2019-10-01/313225100/143/100103/xxx0020190914/900000/12201/-/2500/2019-10-01 01:30:23.250
```

```
public List<Foo_MATISSUE> GetData_MATISSUE()
    {
        List<Foo_MATISSUE> dataListM = new List<Foo_MATISSUE>();
        string connectionString = "Data Source=xxx; Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security = false; User ID=xxx;Password=xxx";
        string selectStatement = "SELECT WarehouseCode,TERM,MFGDATE,PRODUCTITEMCODE,LOTNO,MATITEMCODE,ISSUELOTNO,ISSUEPLANT,ISSUELOCATION,PROCESSCODE,ISSUEQTY,LASTUPDATED from V_MATISSUE where TERM =@TERM;";
        try
        {
            using (var conM = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmdM = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conM))
                {
                    conM.Open();
                    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@TERM";
                    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    parameter.Value = (dateTimePicker1.Value).Date.AddDays(-((dateTimePicker1.Value).Day) + 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
                    using (var readerM = cmdM.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readerM.Read())  //if
                        {
                            dataListM.Add(new Foo_MATISSUE
                            {
                                WarehouseCode = readerM.GetString(0),
                                TERM = readerM.GetDateTime(1),
                                MFGDATE = readerM.GetDateTime(2),
                                PRODUCTITEMCODE = readerM.GetString(3),
                                LOTNO = readerM.GetString(4),
                                MATITEMCODE = readerM.GetString(5),
                                ISSUELOTNO = readerM.GetString(6),
                                ISSUEPLANT = readerM.GetString(7),
                                ISSUELOCATION = readerM.GetString(8),
                                PROCESSCODE = readerM.GetString(9),
                                ISSUEQTY = readerM.GetDouble(10),
                                LASTUPDATED = readerM.GetDateTime(11) 

                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + "\n\n" + e.Message); }
        return dataListM;
    }
```

I think this source code must get 2 rows from the database. But when I debug this code, didn't come in `while (readerM.Read())` loop then it go to `catch` directly with error:

> {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@TERM\"."}

And I try to debug by creating a string parameter for getting the result of

```
 string test = (dateTimePicker1.Value).Date.AddDays(-((dateTimePicker1.Value).Day) + 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  
             // ===> "2019-10-01"
```

Could you help me to find this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a parameter object but you haven't added it to the command's parameter collection.

Following this:

```cs
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@TERM";
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = (dateTimePicker1.Value).Date.AddDays(-((dateTimePicker1.Value).Day) + 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The next thing you need to do before executing the command is add the parameter:

```cs
cmdM.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Ohhh!! Thank you so much. I fixed this problem.